# What is a good way to automatically change the hive-site-xml of AWS EMR at launch time

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

To allow BI Tools like Microstrategy to access data on an AWS EMR cluster with Spark SQL, you have to add a property to the hive-site.xml
We are raising EMR clusters automatically with CloudFormation templates, but have not found a proper way (other than scripting a step) to change the xml within this process.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Potential duplicate with [External hive metastore for EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301995/external-hive-metastore-for-emr) (This question is actually oldest, however, that one has more answers, so I marked this one as duplicate )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the configuration API to change settings during launch. The classification that you need is "hive-site". Example:

```
{
      "Classification": "hive-site",
      "Properties": {
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql:\/\/hostname:3306\/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": "username",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": "password"
      }
    }
```