# Setting Remote hive metastore on postgresql for EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, hive-metastore

I am trying to setup postgresql db as external Hive metastore for AWS EMR.
I have tried hosting it on both EC2 and RDS.

I have already tried steps as given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-external.html).

But it doesnt go through, EMR fails in the provisioning step only with message

> On the master instance (instance-id), application provisioning failed

I could not decipher anything from the failure log.

I also copied postgresql jdbc jar in paths

> /usr/lib/hive/lib/  and  /usr/lib/hive/jdbc/
>   in case EMR doesnt already has it, but still no help!

Then I setup the system by manually editing `hive-site.xml` and setting properties:

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword
datanucleus.fixedDatastore
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables
```

and had to run `hive --service metatool -listFSRoot`.

After these manual settings I was able to get EMR to use postgres db as remote metastore.

Is there any way I can make it work using the configuration file as mentioned in official documentation?

Edit:
Configuration setting I am using to for remote mysql metastore:

classification=hive-site,properties=[javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://[host]:3306/[dbname]?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true,javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver,javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=[user],javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=[pass]]

Comment: The classification is generally a json object. It will be more helpful if you could give full command or function that you are using to start the EMR. Or are you starting up from EMR console?

Comment: Yes! we can provide the configuration settings through json or specify those in the format i have given.
These settings are getting set on EMR. I checked these on EMR before it terminates. so configuration settings is not an issue

Comment: well then you should check the EMR logs for what went wrong during provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

I could never find a clean approach to configure this at the time of EMR startup itself.

The main problem is that EMR initializes the schema with MySQL using the command :

`/usr/lib/hive/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType MySQL`

which should be postgres for our case.

The following manual steps allows to you configure postgres as external metastore:

1) Start EMR cluster with hive application, with default configurations.

2) Stop hive using command :

```
sudo stop hive-server2
```

3) Copy postgresql-jdbc jar (stored in some S3 location) to `/usr/lib/hive/lib/` on EMR

4) Overwrite the default hive-site.xml in `/usr/lib/hive/conf/` with custom one containing the JDO configuration for the Postgresql running on the EC2 node

5) Execute command :

```
sudo /usr/lib/hive/bin/schematool -upgradeSchema -dbType postgres
```

Comment: Right! I was able to configure it all manually using the steps I gave in question, but my requirement is to be able to do it using configuration file itself, like many articles state!  So according to you, if I configure Mysql instead of postgresql on EC2 machine, it will work with configuration file ?

Comment: Yes. We switched to MySQL and it woks absolutely fine.

Comment: Great! Can you please give me exact steps for the same or point me to any article with the steps

Comment: Already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301995/external-hive-metastore-for-emr/48477743

Comment: Could you please accept the above answer for postgres? :-)

Comment: It is actually failing for MySQL too. It fails in provision step as mentioned in the question! I have provided the configuration file just as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Can you check if the MySQL port is accessible from your EMR cluster? You will need to open the port from inbound/outbound settings of your security group.

Or you can also turn of the firewall on the machine which has mysql.

Comment: Yes! I already checked port setting. Mysql is accessible from EMR being provisioned!

Comment: can you share your code that you are using to instantiate the EMR cluster?